# While importing the .txt in excel using Panda the 1st column of data row is removed

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have create a `'~'` delimited file. When I am trying to import this in excel using Pandas, first column of data fields is lost. below is my code

sample records

```
Header1~Header2~Header3~Header4
data1~data2~data3~data4

df = pd.read_csv('file Path', sep='~')

df.to_excel('file path', 'Sheet1')
```

After running the code result is looking like

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4
Data2   Data3   Data4
```

Comment: The code seems to create an Excel output which matches the CSV input. What is the problem?

Comment: @Michael Butscher I updated the result if you see Data2 came under Header1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
df = pd.read_csv('file Path', sep='~', header=0)
df.to_excel('file Path', 'Sheet1')
```

[image]

Maybe your data file, the real one, has some error.

Comment: now result is changed but header1 is moved right and on top of Data 2. column 1 is blank for header row data 1 is showing but no header for that.

Comment: I were you, I would double check your txt file, it seems it might have ~ in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion when I am doing manual import it is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks It worked I was missing a new line indicator on the header records.